# Dispose() doesn't work on every frame

Tags: java, swing, notifications, popup, dispose

My program will alert users when data (stock name & price) in the database matches with the data (stock name and price) from Yahoo Finance. With the help of [HarryJoy](http://harryjoy.com/2011/07/01/create-new-message-notification-pop-up-in-java/) i'm able to implement a pop up notification.

The problem now is, all the functions only works on the last frame (YHOO). It will not dispose() after 5 seconds, or when I click the closeButton. Thanks!

[image: PopUp]

```
    if (stockPriceDB == popStockValue)
    {                       

        String header = "Stock: "  + stock.getTicker() + " is now @ " +  stock.getPrice();          
        String message = "";

        popUpFrame = new JFrame();
        popUpFrame.setSize(320,90); 
        popUpFrame.setUndecorated(true);                                    
        popUpFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 0;
        constraints.weightx = 1.0f;
        constraints.weighty = 1.0f;
        constraints.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        JLabel headingLabel = new JLabel(header);

        ImageIcon headingIcon = new ImageIcon("images/alert.gif");          
        headingLabel.setIcon(headingIcon);          

        popUpFrame.getContentPane().add(headingLabel, constraints);
        constraints.gridx++;
        constraints.weightx = 0f;
        constraints.weighty = 0f;
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;                          

        closeButton = new JButton(); 

        closeButton = new JButton(new AbstractAction("x") 
        {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) 
            {
                popUpFrame.dispose();
            }
        });

        closeButton.setMargin(new Insets(1, 4, 1, 4));
        closeButton.setFocusable(false);
        popUpFrame.getContentPane().add(closeButton, constraints);
        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy++;
        constraints.weightx = 1.0f;
        constraints.weighty = 1.0f;
        constraints.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;                 

        JLabel messageLabel = new JLabel(message);  
        popUpFrame.getContentPane().add(messageLabel, constraints);
        popUpFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        popUpFrame.setVisible(true);

        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        Insets toolHeight = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(popUpFrame.getGraphicsConfiguration());
        popUpFrame.setLocation(screenSize.width - popUpFrame.getWidth(), screenSize.height - toolHeight.bottom - (popUpFrame.getHeight() * (x+1)));

        new Thread()
        {                           
        public void run() 
            {
                try 
                {
                    Thread.sleep(5000); 
                    popUpFrame.dispose(); 
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            };

        }.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that the problem you are getting is that you are passing, to an external code (a different thread in this case), a variable of `popUpFrame` which you then assign new object every instance of the loop.

**This approach is susceptible to errors** as you are loosing the reference you passed. Because you are overwriting it every time you create a new object. 
Therefore, I think you might be only able to close to latest one.

**To avoid something like this** a variable you pass to an external code should always be `final` or when instantiating an external process store a reference to it inside the external code.

Comment: Thanks Boro! I've changed the variables to final and it's working fine now! :)

Comment: popUpFrame.dispose(); should be wrapped into invokeLater, because is called put of EDT, for rest +1

Comment: Great to hear that. I thought so :) Anyway a much better approach would be if you were using just a single thread for updating all visible frames. This way you will avoid creating a separate thread for each frame. The update thread could have a list of frames that are visible, the frames could have their expiry time and it would just check every 30 ms if they are expired or not, and act accordingly. This way you always have 2 threads. Also you could reuse the update thread later, if you like, for animations etc.

Answer (score 4):

As noticed by Boro, you are reusing the same popupFrame variable for all your frames. Of course it can only store a single frame, the last one you created. All the others are lost. So when you call popupFrame.dispose(), you actually dispose the last created `JFrame` independently of the "X" button you pressed

But I think that the choice of making so many frames is actually not a good idea. You should rather have a single JFrame which contains a set of JPanel's which you will remove after 5 seconds or when the 'X' button is pressed.

Comment: Guillaume Polet, thanks for the recommendation and detailed explanation, i understand now :)

Comment: +1 nice one with reusing a single frame, and resizing it accordingly.

Comment: Is there a way to go about creating new frames that wont share the same name, in a situation like this? Yes, I agree that jpanels would probably be your best bet, but would the same name problem still present itself when trying to remove the panel?

Comment: @ShaneKelsey Personnally, I would have a single frame with a vertical box layout. Inside the frame, I would add instances of a class that would extend JPanel. That class would then create the content of the Stock (name & price) and also include the "X" button. From there it is then trivial to remove the parent panel from the hierarchy (and invoke revalidate() on the parent of the panel).